# How to set 1 for all bits without knowing the length of column?

Tags: mysql, sql, bit

I have a bit column like this:

```
// mytable
+---------+------------+ 
|   id    |    numb    |
+---------+------------+
| int(11) |  bit(10)   |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | NULL       |
| 2       | NULL       |
+---------+------------+
```

Not this is **expected result:**

```
// mytable
+---------+------------+ 
|   id    |    numb    |
+---------+------------+
| int(11) |  bit(10)   |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 1111111111 |
| 2       | 1111111111 |
+---------+------------+
```

You know, I can do that like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET numb = b'1111111111';
```

But maybe I will change the length of `numb` column in future and then query above fails. How can I set `1` for all bits without knowing the length of bit-column?

---

**EDIT:** Actually I'm trying to do something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET numb = b'0';
/* output
+---------+------------+ 
|   id    |    numb    |
+---------+------------+
| int(11) |  bit(10)   |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 0000000000 |
| 2       | 0000000000 |
+---------+------------+
*/
```

As you see, I set `0` for all bits without knowing the length of column. Well how can I do that just set `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: you could query the sys tables for the data types, and then use that to identify the length for your insert

Comment: `Select CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'MYTABLE' and schema = 'MYSCHEMA'  and column_Name = 'numb'`  use [lpad](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) with this to pad 1 for each value in length.

Comment: Can you set the value to `-1`, which is all 1s in `two's complement`

Comment: wow .. @Stavr00 well played ..! `UPDATE mytable SET numb = -1;` works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Based on what @Stavr00 said in the comments, I can set the value to `-1`. Something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET numb = -1;

/* output
+---------+------------+ 
|   id    |    numb    |
+---------+------------+
| int(11) |  bit(10)   |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 1111111111 |
| 2       | 1111111111 |
+---------+------------+
*/
```

Comment: Much simpler than my effort :)

Comment: @Matt Yes ... but your query would be correct too. upvote for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the `REPEAT` function and utilise the `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` for the variable.

```
SELECT id, REPEAT('1', (SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
                        FROM information_schema.columns
                        WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()
                        AND table_name = 'mytable'
                        AND COLUMN_NAME = 'numb')) AS numb
FROM mytable
```